# View in a method with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with some fields, a controller that process data of this form and a view to show results.

In the controller, I have a method

```
def formsent
   @a = param[:a_field]
   @b = param[:b_field]
   @c = param[:c_field]
   @d = {aze => "something" ... }
end
```

View :

```
<table>
<tr>
<th><%= @a %></th>
<th><%= @b %></th>
<th><%= @c %></th>
</tr>
<% @d.each do |k,v| %>
<tr>
<th><%= k %></th>
<th><%= v %></th>
<th>Something</th>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

It's whatever... but just to the principle.

Now I would like to show twice the view with just a different field.
Because I would like to compare data.

RoR said : Don't repeat yourself, I don't know how to process the same `formsent` but with a different value in a field. (I'll have 2 same forms)

**Question :** How to show the same view with different values ? (without repeat myself)
The values can be string, integer, hash or array.

It's maybe unclear, I'm sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd steer away from views/methods with a ton of parameters like this and instead consider a parameter object.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this ? I think that I'll have to create an object (or model?) with the `formsent` method and create 2 instances of this with the fields of the form. Then, render the 2 views with the object in parameter. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`How to show the same view with different values ? (without repeat myself) The values can be string, integer, hash or array.`

Create a partial lets say _sample.html.erb containing your code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= a %></th>
    <th><%= b %></th>
    <th><%= c %></th>
  </tr>
  <% d.each do |k,v| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= k %></th>
      <th><%= v %></th>
      <th>Something</th>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Now in your view call this partial twice passing different locals, something like:

```
<%= render partial: "sample", locals: {a: v1, b: v2, c: v3, d: v4} %>  // where v1,v2,v3,v4 are instance variables set in controller

<%= render partial: "sample", locals: {a: v5, b: v6, c: v7, d: v8} %>   // where v5,v6,v7,v8 are instance variables set in controller
```

Comment: `<%= render partial: "sample", locals: {a: @v1, b: @v2, c: @v3, d: @v4} %>` with `@` ? Wow actually I thing that what I want to do is very complicated...

Comment: @Alexis_user i know but your question says `show the same view with different values` if you want to show same code repetitive times in your view with different variables then this is what partials are for. If there are a lot of parameters then change your approach as @dave suggested

Comment: I valid you, I'll repost another question when I'll well thought. Yes, I'll try to change my approach.